# How to efficiently (and aesthetically) display an evolving publications list on your webpage?

Tags: website

I'm building a personal website where I'd like to list my publications. Perhaps one of the most efficient ways to do that would be to use or build something that pulls data from an online bib file, and lists entries. I found [BibBase](https://bibbase.org/), but it has only a few options for display styles, and seems difficult to use if you want something that's also visually pleasing. Short of actually building the html page on your own, what are some common methods that people find useful for this task? How about any websites that you think do this very well?

Answer (score 11):

*(this is close to a shopping question, so I see some danger of this being closed - however, I think the question comes up for enough people in academia that it warrants an answer here)*

What I have found most efficient is to indeed generate the publication list from a hosted bibtex file. The solution that I went for is to have a repository at [Github Sites](https://pages.github.com) where I can commit my bibtex file (and any other static resources I want in my web page, including pictures and preprints), and then I generate the actual publication list using JavaScript code I extracted from the [bibtexify](https://github.com/martinec/grav-plugin-bibtexify) project.

The result looks like that, which I find visually quite pleasing:

[image: Screenshot]

A live version is available on my [website](http://philippleitner.net/research/publications/). To get access to the code you can clone my [public GitHub repo](https://github.com/xleitix/publication_list). Then the actual publication list can be rendered on any website using some JS/CSS code. This should work either in a stand-alone Web site, integrated into whatever your university uses for hosting (as long as JavaScript / CSS code is allowed), or a CMS such as Wordpress.

Advantages of this approach:

- Easy to update (just update the bibtex file and commit it)
- Responsive (also works nice on mobile etc.)
- Very few assumptions on the hosting environment - it just needs to support JavaScript and CSS.

Disadvantages of this approach:

- Setting everything up is a bit hacky as you need to plumb together some JS/CSS code (but once it works I found the solution to be quite stable)

If there is interest I can try to find some time to write more detailed instructions on how to set everything up.

Answer (score 2):

Some use Google scholar. The advantages are

- that much data are already gathered by Google itself
- high chances that people know how to use it
- it is professionally designed and will be updated from time to time
- it calculates some metrics
- not much effort

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this depends on how many new publications you get per month/year/whatever.

If you are early-career and it is only a few, then the most "efficient" way is probably to manually maintain a web page (whether that is by editing HTML, or editing a Wordpress site, or whatever). The overhead of setting up an automated system will probably take years to pay back, by which time it will be obsolete in some way anyway - and some monitoring and intervention will probably be required anyway so that Google Scholar's notions of what a "publication" is don't make it to your page.

If you are a senior academic who, through co-authorship, publishes multiple times a month, then this may work out differently.