# Displaying publication results in website

Tags: publications, code, website

First time here.
My background is in biomedical science, so I have no knowledge of coding whatsoever.

Since I was tasked with building a website for my lab, I used WIX as my website builder. I based my query on this question asked half a decade ago:

[How to efficiently (and aesthetically) display an evolving publications list on your webpage?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109114/how-to-efficiently-and-aesthetically-display-an-evolving-publications-list-on)

Similar to the post, I am trying to create an element on the page where there is a display of publications published. I tried to use the code provided in the original query (sadly, I just copied and pasted) to see if the code worked. I turned on Dev Mode and copied and pasted the JS (JavaScript) code. To no one's surprise, the website doesn't change. Not even an error.

My challenge is that I don't know which code I should change or not change. I am aware that I need to study coding a bit more before doing such a task, but I do hope someone more experienced and expert on this can help out a bit more.

I was wondering if anyone has step-by-step instructions on how to go with this query.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered [SO: stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for technical/coding solutions?.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is an appropriate question for Academia - probably better for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). But I'll give it a go anyway.

Step by step instructions are probably unrealistic here. Disclaimer - I'm not familiar with WIX and I'm not a web developer. But I have done enough coding work to maybe be helpful. I have some thoughts:

1. I'm not sure what code you are copying to where but, if you are using the [bibtexify](https://github.com/martinec/grav-plugin-bibtexify) package, it looks too complex for a copy-paste.
2. It seems like the plugin you want to use was written for GRAV, the JS code *might* work with a different CMS (like WIX) but I don't know for sure and I wouldn't bet on it.
3. At the end of the day, the chance that someone's custom plugin works on the first go in an entirely different system without modification is like 0%. You'll need to learn a bit of JS and see if you can rewrite the code to work.

So what should you do? If you can't find something made for WIX then you have to modify what you've got.

I would look for WIX tutorials that go over adding custom plugins/code. You should check out this [link](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-about-embeds-and-codes-on-your-site) which talks about adding custom code to WIX websites as a start.

I would also watch/read some JS tutorials. You'll need to be able to at least read the code if you want to do anything useful with it.

Once you do that, you need to figure out what the code does and how. And what the differences are between GRAV and WIX. That way you can implement the plugin in the new environment.

That being said, if you have no coding experience, let alone any JS/web dev experience, this might be tough. I *think* that this is a deceivingly complicated implementation for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if Academia might get you technical solutions you seek.

For the coding part of the existing JavaScript solution you referred to, you may be better off engaging on the [SO site](https://stackoverflow.com/): such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038703/converting-bibtex-files-to-html-with-python-maybe-pybtex).

For general approach and for Python solutions, you may consider the following:

- [publistgen: generate static publication lists from bibtex files](https://github.com/t-wissmann/publistgen)
- [Publication list creation with bibtex and python](https://www.j4s8.de/post/2020-05-12-publication-list-creation/)

Answer (score 0):

A very quick (very dirty?) solution you might use while you figure out something better: link to a google scholar page.

https://biology.ucdavis.edu/about/faculty-staff-resources/IT/google-scholar